# Грамматический разбор: «Убить Россию — это значит отнять надежду у Земли»

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

«Убить Россию — это значит отнять надежду у Земли».

Я сделала так: Подлежащее — *убить Россию,* сказуемое — *значит отнять,* но теперь я не могу понять, это составное глагольное сказуемое или составное именное, с глаголом-связкой "значит". Правильно ли я разобрала?

Comment: Подлежащее неверно и сказуемое неверно. "Значит" – не связка.

Comment: *Подлежащее неверно и сказуемое неверно. "Значит" – не связка* - опрос проводили? @Soofiya, не берите это в голову, вообще-то, если человек беспредметно критикует, но дает своего варианта, то это обычное чувство собственного высокомерия.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

> *«Убить Россию — это значит отнять надежду у Земли».*
>
> Я сделала так: подлежащее — *убить Россию*...

Наверное, правильнее будет считать ***Россию*** дополнением, а подлежащим —  инфинитив ***убить***.

> сказуемое — *значит отнять*...

Сказуемое  —  ***это значит отнять*** (*составное именное*), где ***это значит***  — связка, ***отнять*** —  именная часть сказуемого.

===

Из комментария в этой теме:

> За наречием еще признали (со скрипом) право выступать в роли именной
>   части СИС, а вот насчет глагола, пусть даже инфинитива, - это некая
>   новация.

Нет, не новация!  Именной частью составного именного сказуемого  более полувека назад считали инфинитив в предложениях  типа ***Учить  —  ум точить***, к примеру, такие лингвисты, как **Д. Э. Розенталь** и **В. А. Добромыслов** (*В. А. Добромыслов и Д. Э. Розенталь "Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания. Пособие для учителей." Выпуск второй. М., 1960*):

> По своей функции инфинитив в предложениях ***Учить  —  ум точить; Цель
>   наша — правду отстоять, мир для людей*** и т. п.  ближе стоит к
>   предикативному члену (именной части) **именного сказуемого**.  На
>   такой точке зрения стоял, в частности, А. М. Пешковский… Не следует
>   также забывать, что неопределённая форма глагола по происхождению  —
>   имя и что в настоящее время инфинитив соотносится с именем
>   существительным, например: *Наша задача  — учиться* и *Наша задача — 
>   учение.*
>
> Правда, самый термин "именное сказуемое" предполагает наличие в нём
>   какого-нибудь имени (существительного, прилагательного, числительного,
>   местоимения). Однако, как известно,  предикативный член может быть
>   выражен также причастием, деепричастием (очень редко), наречием (в том
>   числе предикативным наречием, или безлично-предикативным словом),
>   междометием, т. е. частями речи, которые к именам не относятся (только
>   причастие стоит к ним ближе как именная глагольная форма). **В плане
>   такой условности можно отнести сюда и инфинитив…**

Так же характеризует инфинитив в подобных предложениях и **Лекант** (*П. А. Лекант, Е. И. Диброва, Л. Л. Касаткин и др. "Современный русский язык", М., 2007*):

> Инфинитив в **составном именном сказуемом** не утрачивает значение
>   действия, но выступает в качестве характеристики предмета (или
>   другого, независимого действия), названного в подлежащем. Инфинитив
>   сочетается только со связками ***быть, значить, означать:***
>
> *Играть в карты  — **значит обкрадывать** товарища; Наша учительская миссия  — **защитить** детскую душу.*

Правда,  некоторые лингвисты по-другому квалифицируют такие сказуемые.  Так, [**Литневская**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#31202) относит их к СГС:

> Особый тип СГС представлен в предложениях, главные члены которых
>   выражены глаголами в неопределенной форме:
>
> *Волков бояться — в лес **не ходить**.*

У **Федосюка** (*"Синтаксис современного русского языка", М., 2012*) подобные сказуемые названы инфинитивными.

Но всё же в большей части мне известных пособий такие сказуемые считаются **составными именными**.

К примеру, составным именным считается сказуемое в справочнике школьника (*Е. А. Панова и А. А. Позднякова "Русский язык. Учебно-справочное пособие", М., 2010; "Материалы книги соответствуют формату Единого государственного издания..."*) в таком предложении:

> *Любить — **значит бороться** и **побеждать**.*

Так же рассматривает подобные сказуемые и **Г. И. Кустова** (*"Синтаксис современного русского языка", М., 2013*):

> Инфинитив встречается как в составном глагольном, **так и в составном
>   именном сказуемом**.  В первом случае он зависит от вспомогательного
>   глагола (*хочет / может / начал читать*), во втором соединяется с
>   подлежащим с помощью связок ***это, значит, всё равно что*** и т. п.:
>
> *Любить  — **это жертвовать** самим собой;*
>
> *Остановиться  — **значит погибнуть***

Comment: Боюсь, Вас не все поймут с такой ***именной*** частью. За наречием еще признали (со скрипом) право выступать в роли именной части СИС, а вот насчет глагола, пусть даже инфинитива, - это некая новация. Хотя я понимаю, откуда ноги растут у подобных суждений (*от недостаточной модальности глагола "значить"*), но надо все-таки как-то поаккуратнее.  формулировать... Я было даже написал, что это СГС, но понял, что тоже дал маху..Получается, "убить" - дополнение.

Comment: _behemothus: Боюсь, Вас не все поймут с такой **именной** частью. За наречием еще признали (со скрипом) право выступать в роли именной части СИС, а вот насчет глагола, пусть даже инфинитива, - это некая новация._  === Нет, не новация! Или, во всяком случае, не моя _новация_.  Постараюсь сейчас дополнить свой ответ.

Comment: Да, что-то не знал я всего этого, спасибо... Я уточню, я и не говорил, что это **Ваша*** новация, о попытках объфить инфинитив именной частью СИС я был немного наслышан.  Но недоумения моего не снимает. Понимаете какая штука, с примерами Розенталя я могу согласится, там тире заменяет глагол-связку "быть", тогда понятно, откуда берется сама идея  о СИС. Но у вас-то (вслед за некоторыми процитированными современными авторами, что ли) в роли вспомогательного глагола выступает  "значит" с весьма слабой модальностью.

Comment: При по сути смысловом глаголе интерпретировать инфинитив как именную часть - что-то не вижу резона. А кто-нибудь  из цитируемых авторов указывал, ***что именно*** он полагает вспомогательным глаголом в таком СГС? Точно ли глагол типа "значит", а не опушенный глагол-связку? Со вторым, я еще готов согласиться.

Comment: Вот Кустова, как я понимаю, считает "значит" связкой. Только не соображу, глагольной ли, точно не вспомогательной частицей?!

Comment: _behemothus: Точно ли глагол типа "значит", а не опущенный глагол-связку?_ === 

Конечно, точно. При наличии у связки _**это значит**_  форм прош.  _**это значило**_, буд. _**это будет значить**_, сослагат. _**это значило бы**_ (такие формы приведены в словарях под ред. Морковкина) никаких дополнительных глаголов-связок не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Вот до чего докумекал.

"Убить Россию" - группа подлежащего (ну или "убить" - подлежащее, Россия - дополнение, это уже детали и отдельный разговор),
"это значит"  - частица *(!!!*),
"отнять ..." - группа сказуемого, "отнять" - инфинитивное сказуемое,   "надежду" и "у Земли" - дополнения (хотя тут тоже не все очевидно, но, вроде, так),
тире - показывает **отсутствие** связки между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Вот примерчик похожий (раздел II) 
http://www.goldrussian.ru/tire-mezhdu-podlezhashhim-i-skazuemym.html

Comment: Как же всё-таки хочется понять, насколько вы правы или, наоборот неправы, считая "вроде" вводным словом и обособляя его!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Я его использую в качестве вводного - и потому обособляю. Оно у меня в подобных случаях (но далеко не во всех, разумеется) синонимично "кажется", "думаю" и относится к глаголу или ко всей фразе в целом. Если к другой части речи, то не вводное, конечно.

Comment: Понятно, просто хочется побольше мнений авторитетных людей насчёт вашей правоты услышать.

Comment: А я не претендую на какаю-то общую правоту. Это тот случай, когда каждый сам себе хозяин. Ту же самую фразу могу (гипотетически) написать и без обособления, просто тогда будут другие акценты, в данном случае для меня нежелательные. Так что здесь "опросом" можно решить разве вопрос, имею ли я право выбирать авторскую пунктуацию из двух в принципе возможных. Вот "как бы" я так не напишу даже в значении, синонимичном "вроде", ну не получается оно у меня вводным по смыслу, хотя допускаю, что для кого-то и оно в роли вводного возможно. Это свобода в рамках закона, трудно что-то запретить.

Comment: Понятно, интересно всё это.)